# Adding values in textbox, dropdown menus and checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have to get the total of the values in my textboxes, checkbox(if it is checked, if not, it will be ignored or 0) and dropdown(whatever the customer wishes to choose, its value will be added to the list of payments). In short, I need it to be something like this.

total = textboxA + textboxB + the value in the checkbox + the selected price in dropdown;

i have this so far...

**javascript**

```
function subtotal(){
var a = document.getElementById("sff").value;
var b = document.getElementById("osf").value

var stotal = parseInt(a)+ parseInt(b);
document.getElementById("st").innerHTML = "$" + stotal;
```

}

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="sff" placeholder="$0.00" value=""  onchange="subtotal()" style="float:left;"/>
<input type="text" id="off" placeholder="$0.00" value=""  onchange="subtotal()" style="float:left;"/>
<select style="margin: 3px 0 0 55px; width:48%; position: absolute; float: left; ">
                <option value="a1">$99.00 (1yr)</option>
                <option value="a2">$178.20 (2yrs)</option>
                <option value="a3">$241.56 (3yrs)</option>
 </select>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx2"/>($35.00) - Shipping
```

**this not the way I write the codes, i just get the important parts....

Comment: what is the problem actually???your code seems to be right..

Comment: This is not `Java`. Remove it from you tags.

Comment: i have to add the value in the textbox in my function subtotal as well as the value in my dropdown. as you can see, the only the textboxes are in my function subtotal. @Lal

Comment: do it same way itself..ie `var c = document.getElementById("selctid").value;`

Comment: dont forget to give id for the select as `selectid`..

Comment: and how do i call my `subtotal()` function? i have `<input type="text" id="total"/>` i know that it is not `onclick`

Comment: simplest idea would be to keep a button and call the function on onclick

Comment: but what if i want it to automatically appear on the textbox?

Comment: then i think you'll have to check for the change in the status of the checkbox..call the function on selection change..ie call it when checked..

Comment: ie `document.getElementById('cbx2').onchange = function() {
    if ( document.getElementById('cbx2').checked === true) {
        subtotal();
    }
};​`

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/o90f31dx/)..here, on selecting the checkbox the value is automatically populated in a textbox..